# Reading then modifying JSON with rustc_serialize

Tags: json, rust, rust-crates

So let's say I want to replace `{"foo": 13}` with `{"foo": 14}`. Attempt:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json::Json;

fn main() {
    let data = Json::from_str("{\"foo\": 13, \"bar\": \"baz\"}").unwrap();
    let mut obj = data.as_object().unwrap();
    let somenum: u64 = 14;
    obj.insert(String::from_str("foo"), Json::U64(somenum));

    for (key, value) in obj.iter() {
        println!("{}: {}", key, match *value {
            Json::U64(v) => format!("{} (u64)", v),
            Json::String(ref v) => format!("{} (string)", v),
            _ => format!("other")
        });
    }
}
```

Error:

```
src/main.rs:8:5: 8:8 error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*obj` \
                            as mutable
src/main.rs:8     obj.insert(String::from_str("foo"), Json::U64(somenum));
                  ^~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`as_object`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/json/enum.Json.html#method.as_object) returns `Option<&Object>`—an immutable reference.

To get a mutable reference (`Option<&mut Object>`), you must use [`as_object_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/json/enum.Json.html#method.as_object_mut).